# Swift capitalise first letter of each word in string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking to capitalise the first letter of each word in a string. For Example:

stack overflow --> Stack Overflow

STACK OVERFLOW --> Stack Overflow

Does anyone know to accomplish this in swift 3?

Answer (score 18):

Call capitalized function on your string as follows.

```
var str = "hello, playground"
str.capitalized
print(str.capitalized)
```

Output
`Hello, Playground`